# Transfer data from solr to python

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

I am beginner to solr.i want to transfer the data from solr to python and i have found the pysolr library i have installed it but did'nt know how to use it. I have searched on google but did'nt find required answer

I want to ask how we can load data from solr to python and perform filtering,sorting and other operations

i have tried as:

```
from pysolr import Solr
conn = Solr('/localhost:8983/solr/sms_data/select?indent=on&q=customer_id:73614&rows=10&start=0&wt=json')
```

Now how can i read the data present in conn and perform other operations.

Comment: What have you tried? What is it about the example given in [pysolrs README](https://github.com/django-haystack/pysolr) that you don't understand?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is the *complete* Solr query string. That's not how you use pysolr. From pysolr's README (adapter to your example):

```
# Setup a Solr instance. 
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/sms_data')

results = solr.search('customer_id:73614')

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Further functionality can be added as parameters to the `.search` method, such as fq (you'll have to use the kwargs-style if you want to include parameters with `.` in them):

```
results = solr.search('customer_id:73614', fq='field:value')

# or

result = solr.search('*:*', **{
    'fl': 'content',
    'facet': 'true',
    'facet.field': 'field_name'
})
```